# unresolved identifier in Swift

Tags: swift

I can not resolve this problem in Swift and Xcode

*error swift use of unresolved identifier*

// Configure the cell...

```
    cell.textLabel?.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]

    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages [indexPath.row])

    return cell

}
```

Comment: can you share all function?

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:

NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:

                indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

            

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.textLabel.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages[indexPath.row])

Comment: Can you clarify whether its only swift, or a swift and objective-c program.  Can you also indicate which particular identifier it thinks is unresolved.

Comment: @SandroNogueira clica na célula e da um nome "reusableCell" no interface builder do Xcode no inspector do lado direito em cima  uma das abas depois usa o mesmo nome ai no seu código coloca entre aspas "reusableCell" nó lugar de cellidentifier

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/images/8/8d/Xcode_6_set_cell_id.png

Comment: @SandroNogueira add the missing code You have added to the comments to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you have to identify your tableViewCell with its storyboard id, in this case it is `Cell`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell
{
    var cell:CustomTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell 
    cell!.textLabel?.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
    cell!.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages [indexPath.row])
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: let me try! just second...

Comment: i' ve edited my answer try that

Comment: great because not's work, but let me try again

Comment: easy way just add that line in your viewDidLoad  tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell"). tableView here is your tableView instance name